# why unable to set value to input using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this html code, display a table

```html
<table id="tabel-item-borrowed" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="headtabel">Categories</th>
      <th class="headtabel">Description</th>
      <th class="headtabel">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="t11">
      <td>
        <input id="catinfo[1]" type="text" name="catinfo1" size="40">
        <input id="categories[1]" type="text" name="categories1" size="40">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="description[1]" type="text" name="description1" size="40">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="delete[1]" type="button" name="delete" value="delete" size="5">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="t12">
      <td>
        <input id="catinfo[1]" type="text" name="catinfo1" size="40">
        <input id="categories[2]" type="text" name="categories2" size="40">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="description[2]" type="text" name="description2" size="40">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="delete[2]" type="button" name="delete" value="delete" size="5">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

i want to fill value inside `<input id="catinfo[1]" type="text" name="catinfo1" size="40">` using javascript. this is my code

and this javascript to fill value from php function into html input

```js
$("input#idposinfo").val('');
                $("input#categories\\[" + lastrow + "\\]").val(category);
                $("input#description\\[" + lastrow + "\\]").val(description);
                //succes fill the value inside catinfo
                //$("input#catinfo\\[" + lastrow +"\\]" ).val(category);  

                $.post("get_category_info/" + $('#combocategory1').val() + "/" + $('#combocategory2').val(), {}, function (obj) {
                    console.log("get obj value");
                    console.log(obj); //value in obj is int 25
      $("input#catinfo\\["+lastrow+"\\]").val(obj);
                    console.log("success get obj value");
                });
                lastrow++;
                $("input#lastrow").val(lastrow);
```

inside $.post, the `$("input#catinfo\\[" + lastrow +"\\]" ).val(category);` did not work

how do i fill value from `$.post` ?

Comment: what is the value of `lastrow` ? I am asking this because you are incrementing it outside the asynchronous call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because POST call is asynchronous so success function get executed later but due to closure  in success function you get updated lastrow value which causing the issue:

try setting another local variable which didn't get updated:

```
var rowToUpdate = lastrow;
$.post("get_category_info/" + $('#combocategory1').val() + "/" + $('#combocategory2').val(), {}, function (obj) {
    $("input#catinfo\\["+rowToUpdate+"\\]").val(obj);
    console.log("success get obj value");
});
```